# VBA can't find the existing IE sessions

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

There are many articles dealing with finding the existing IE sessions and then working with them. For some reason, they don't work for me.

I have the following code which creates IE 11 sessions. Sometimes, I manually terminated the VBA code. That left the IE session as an orphan.

```
Set IE = GetObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
If IE Is Nothing Then Set IE = CreateObject("INTERNETEXPLORER.APPLICATION")
With IE
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate  URL
```

I have found many articles with all sorts of code to find the existing IE sessions but they don't work for me. The following code is an example.

```
Sub test_is()

Dim IE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

On Error Resume Next
Set IE = GetObject(, "InternetExplorer.Application")
Debug.Print Err.Description
On Error GoTo 0

If IE Is Nothing Then
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
If IE Is Nothing Then
Debug.Print "error getting IE"
Else
IE.Quit
End If
End If
End Sub
```

When it got to "Set IE = GetObject(, "InternetExplorer.Application")", Debug.Print reported that "ActiveX component can't create object
".

As the code went on, an IE session was created and then quit. That's the only IE session quit. The other IE sessions which had been created by other code stayed intact. I have tried at least six codes I found on the NET. They work for some people but never work for me.

The following is another example:

```
Sub Find_IE_Windows()

Dim Shell As Object
Dim IE As Object

Set Shell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

For Each IE In Shell.Windows
    If TypeName(IE.Document) = "HTMLDocument" Then
        MsgBox "Internet Explorer window found:" & vbCrLf & _
            "LocationURL=" & IE.LocationURL & vbCrLf & _
            "LocationName=" & IE.LocationName
        IE.Quit
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

In my case, the Shell.Windows.Count was zero. So, the code went from the For loop directly to End Sub.

In other cases, Shell.Windows.Count were 2 when I had excel, IE 11 and MS Edge running. And those two shell windows were File Explorer sessions, not Excel, not Edge, not IE 11.

I have Microsoft Internet Controls, Microsoft HTML Object Library, Microsoft Shell Control and Automation all checked. Am I missing some other library?

The only code that works is this one but it stops MS Edge from getting online. So, can't use it.

```
Sub IE_Sledgehammer()
Dim objWMI As Object, objProcess As Object, objProcesses As Object
Set objWMI = GetObject("winmgmts://.")
Set objProcesses = objWMI.ExecQuery( _
    "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = 'iexplore.exe'")
For Each objProcess In objProcesses
    Call objProcess.Terminate
Next
Set objProcesses = Nothing: Set objWMI = Nothing
End Sub
```

I'm running Windows 10 Pro and Excel 2010.

Comment: What do you mean by _stops MS Edge from getting online_ ? You cannot relaunch and use it to navigate to a page? You can look at using API calls like FindWindow though they are a bitter trickier than the above.

Comment: When I refreshed a page or opened a new link, Edge just waited, waited, and waited. I have to quit it then relaunch it for it to work again.

Comment: "All your versions above work." Yeah, that's my problem. They did not work for me. I wanted to close the existing IE sessions. They just didn't/couldn't do it. As I stated above, when I had two IE 11 sessions open and finished running those codes, the two IE 11 sessions were still there. How to close these two sessions? That's what I have been struggling even now.

Comment: Check whether you have any pending Windows updates or not. If there are any updates available then install it. If possible then for a testing purpose try to use the any latest Office versions to make a test to check whether code works or not. Your code is working on my side with Windows 10 and office 2016.

Comment: Thanks. I'm sure the code works for other people, just not for me. I'm running Windows 10 and office 2010. Not sure when I'll be able to upgrade to Office 2016. Hopefully soon.